# How to implement PayPal to Xcode obj c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, paypal

Is it possible to implement PayPal into Xcode 7.3 Objective C? 
I'm trying to sell a product online, but i need to be able to access PayPal via the application. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer paypal's official ios-integration guide from [this link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/) and here is the paypal's ios sdk project on github [click here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK). Hope this will help. :)